# Dynamic hide form fields for different action

Tags: magento-1, adminform, admin-controller

I have 2 action in `IndexController`: `newAction()` and `editAction()`.

Both those actions will use a same form (about 5 inputs: `First Name, Last Name, Email, Status, Example`)

But in the `newAction()`, I just want to show 2 inputs: **Email and Status**,
while in the `editAction()`, I want to show **full 5 inputs**.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much

**EDIT:**

Hi @Mihai MATEI,

I've updated my code, this is my `_prepareForm()` function

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getSimpleAffiliateData()) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getSimpleAffiliateData();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setSimpleAffiliateData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('simpleaffiliate_data'))
            $data = Mage::registry('simpleaffiliate_data')->getData();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('simpleaffiliate_form',
            array('legend' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Account information')));
        $actionName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
        if ($actionName == 'new') {
            $fieldset->addField('customer_id', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Customer'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'customer_id',
                'values' => $this->getListCustomer(),
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
            $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Status'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'status',
                'values' => array('1' => 'Enable', '2' => 'Disable'),
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
        } else if ($actionName == 'edit') {
            $fieldset->addField('customer_id', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Customer'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'customer_id',
                'values' => $this->getListCustomer(),
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
            $fieldset->addField('first_name', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'First Name',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'first_name',
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('last_name', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Last Name',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'last_name',
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('email', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'class' => 'required-entry validate-email',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'email',
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('balance', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Balance',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'balance',
                    'readonly' => true,
                    'disabled' => true
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('total_received', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Total Received'),
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'total_received',
                    'readonly' => true,
                    'disabled' => true
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('joined', 'date',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Joined',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'joined',
                    'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                    'input_format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                    'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                    'time' => true
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Status'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'status',
                'values' => array('1' => 'Enable', '2' => 'Disable'),
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
        }


        $form->setValues($data);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

But when I go to newAction, it still shows every other fields. What wrong with my code? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better idea to use `registry(Mage::registry()).`

The registry will have id whenver `an object is created  and it data exits`

```
.
if(Mage::registry('simpleaffiliate_data'))->getId()):
// show First Name, Last Name,Example on edit action
endif;
```

**Code:**

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getSimpleAffiliateData()) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getSimpleAffiliateData();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setSimpleAffiliateData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('simpleaffiliate_data'))
            $data = Mage::registry('simpleaffiliate_data')->getData();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('simpleaffiliate_form',
            array('legend' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Account information')));
        $actionName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();

            $fieldset->addField('customer_id', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Customer'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'customer_id',
                'values' => $this->getListCustomer(),
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
            $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Status'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'status',
                'values' => array('1' => 'Enable', '2' => 'Disable'),
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
        if (Mage::registry('simpleaffiliate_data'))->getId()) {

            $fieldset->addField('first_name', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'First Name',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'first_name',
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('last_name', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Last Name',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'last_name',
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('email', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'class' => 'required-entry validate-email',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'email',
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('balance', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Balance',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'balance',
                    'readonly' => true,
                    'disabled' => true
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('total_received', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('simpleaffiliate')->__('Total Received'),
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'total_received',
                    'readonly' => true,
                    'disabled' => true
                ));
            $fieldset->addField('joined', 'date',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Joined',
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'joined',
                    'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                    'input_format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                    'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                    'time' => true
                ));

        }


        $form->setValues($data);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActionName()` method to check which action was called, and display your inputs accordingly:

```
$actionName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
if($actionName == 'edit'){
//...add the other three input fields
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mihai MATEI I've updated my code. Please check. Thank you

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted. I've checked the solution and works for me. Make sure you changed the correct file! Also check if there is some caching going on (some plugin caching forms, also clear Magento cache just to be sure)